# windows store apps 8.1 how to handle IHttpFilter.SendRequestAsync method exception?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, windows-store-apps

in windows store app 8.1 i am trying to add custom filter to requests so i can add authorization header every thing is working fine. however when the server goes down i get an exception in the store app of type `System.AccessViolationException`
her is the code.

```
   try
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await innerFilter.SendRequestAsync(request);
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                    {
                        ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).Navigate(typeof(LoginPage));
                        return response;
                    }
                    return response;
                }
                catch
                {
                     HttpResponseMessage responseEx = new HttpResponseMessage ();
                    responseEx.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                    return responseEx;
                }
```

how i can o handle this type of exception. i have read about https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn263240.aspx
but still do not get it 
her is the full code of the filter

```
public IAsyncOperationWithProgress<HttpResponseMessage, HttpProgress> SendRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            return AsyncInfo.Run<HttpResponseMessage, HttpProgress>(async (cancellationToken, progress) =>
            {
                if ((App.userData != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(App.userData.Token)) || App.Get_user()) 
                {
                     request.Headers.Add("AuthorizationHeader", App.userData.Token);
                }
                try
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await innerFilter.SendRequestAsync(request);
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                    {
                        ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).Navigate(typeof(LoginPage));
                        return response;
                    }
                    return response;
                }
                catch
                {
                     HttpResponseMessage responseEx = new HttpResponseMessage ();
                    responseEx.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                    return responseEx;
                }

            });
        }
```

Comment: is this background thread?

Comment: No it is just a custom http filter

Comment: i think that AsyncInfo.Run is cussing the problem